# Unicode chars during XSL transformation

Tags: java, xml, xslt, unicode

I am working on XML transformation using XSL in Java program. This is the sample XML

```
<root>
 <body>Body goes here &#x2019; with special characters</body>
</root>
```

I want to transform the XML to the following:

```
<root>
 <body>Body goes here &amp;rsquo; with special characters</body>
</root>
```

How to convert Unicode Hex char to Html entity code? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way in XSLT of generating entity references. You can do it "by hand" using disable-output-escaping (or in 2.0, character maps), but it's hard work.

If you are generating HTML, and using Saxon, then there's an xsl:output property

```
<xsl:output saxon:character-representation="entity;hex" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>
```

See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters